# How to update a file data efficiently using numpy.save?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, save, iteration

I'm struggling with the way my data is being saved/updated. I have to calculate positions, velocities and more, multiple times and these variables depend on the lastest calculated value. It would easier, if I just save the data at the end of the for loop, but this loop takes a lot of time and in my region the power outages are often. Thence, the data would not be saved.

I store the data in a numpy file each X iterations as a backup like this:

```
import numpy as np

def calculations(variables):
        'some calculations'
        return variables

for i in range(long value):
        variables=calculations(variables)
        if i%X_iterations==0:
             np.save(path+'/variables.npy',variables)
```

I think there must be a more efficient method to update this file, isn't it? Every millisecond counts.

EDIT:

All data are 1D and 2D numpy arrays. The operations inside calculations are multiplications and sums.

Comment: Without knowing the exact data or operations being performed in the calculation, we can only guess. Some options would be: 1) using numpy [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to speed up `calculations`. 2) Instead of saving the whole numpy array, store the values in a `csv` file, where you keep appending the last value. Then you only have to load the last value to continue.

Comment: All data are 1D and 2D numpy arrays, that's why I was using [.npy format](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format). I prefer not to use csv, because npy stores the shape of variables.